# Escape Pods Google Foobar Challenge | Max Flow Problem

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, depth-first-search, max-flow

I am on 4th level of the google foobar challenge. And I am facing issues in the question. I have tried my solution on the provided test cases but the grade checker of google shows that my code is wrong for those test cases as well. Can anybody help me? Where exactly am I wrong?

## Problem

## Escape Pods

Given the starting room numbers of the groups of bunnies, the room numbers of the escape pods, and how many bunnies can fit through at a time in each direction of every corridor in between, figure out how many bunnies can safely make it to the escape pods at a time at peak.

Write a function solution(entrances, exits, path) that takes an array of integers denoting where the groups of gathered bunnies are, an array of integers denoting where the escape pods are located, and an array of an array of integers of the corridors, returning the total number of bunnies that can get through at each time step as an int. The entrances and exits are disjoint and thus will never overlap. The path element path[A][B] = C describes that the corridor going from A to B can fit C bunnies at each time step.  There are at most 50 rooms connected by the corridors and at most 2000000 bunnies that will fit at a time.

For example, if you have:

```
entrances = [0, 1]

exits = [4, 5]

path = 

[
[0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0],  # Room 0: Bunnies

[0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0],  # Room 1: Bunnies
  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4],  # Room 2: Intermediate room
  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6],  # Room 3: Intermediate room
  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # Room 4: Escape pods
  
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # Room 5: Escape pods
]
```

Then in each time step, the following might happen:
0 sends 4/4 bunnies to 2 and 6/6 bunnies to 3
1 sends 4/5 bunnies to 2 and 2/2 bunnies to 3
2 sends 4/4 bunnies to 4 and 4/4 bunnies to 5
3 sends 4/6 bunnies to 4 and 4/6 bunnies to 5

So, in total, 16 bunnies could make it to the escape pods at 4 and 5 at each time step.  (Note that in this example, room 3 could have sent any variation of 8 bunnies to 4 and 5, such as 2/6 and 6/6, but the final solution remains the same.)

## Test cases

Your code should pass the following test cases.
Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.

-- Python cases --
Input:

```
solution.solution([0], [3], [[0, 7, 0, 0], [0, 0, 6, 0], [0, 0, 0, 8], [9, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Output:

```
6
```

Input:

```
solution.solution([0, 1], [4, 5], [[0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Output:

```
16
```

## My Solution

```
def get_new_path(entrances,exits,path):
    for p in path:
        p.insert(0, 0)
        p.append(0)
    new_length = len(path[0])
    path.insert(0,[0]* new_length)
    path.append([0]* new_length)
    for e in entrances:
        path[0][e+1] = 2e+6
    for e in exits:
        path[e+1][new_length-1] =  2e+6
    return path

def get_route(stack, open, path):
    next = stack[-1]
    list_of_nexts = [i for i,val in enumerate(path[next]) if ( i not in open and val != 0)]
    for i in list_of_nexts:
        open.add(i)
    if len(path)-1 in list_of_nexts:
        stack.append(len(path)-1)
        return stack
    for i in list_of_nexts:
        new_stack = stack.copy()
        new_stack.append(i)
        r = get_route(new_stack, open, path)
        if r == -1: continue
        else: return r
    return -1
    
def solution(entrances, exits, path):
    path = get_new_path(entrances, exits, path)
    flow = 0
    while True:
        stack = [0]
        open = set()
        open.add(0)
        route = get_route(stack, open, path)
        if(route == -1):
            return flow
        else:
            f = min([path[route[i-1]][route[i]] for i in range(1,len(route))])
            for i in range(2,len(route)-1):
                temp = path[route[i-1]][route[i]]
                path[route[i-1]][route[i]] = temp - f
                path[route[i]][route[i-1]] += f
            flow += f    
    return flow

print(solution([0, 1], [4, 5], [[0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your solution ever works on your own computer but not on the Foobar autograder, just know that there are a few things that the Autograder **does not allow**, that immediately results in a compile error:

1. Any print statements: print statements are not allowed (in fact, no System input or output operations are allowed). By looking at your code it seems you have a print statement. Get rid of it and try again.
2. Missing 'Solution' class and method. If you accidentally changed the name of the class while editing the file on your own editor, make sure to change it back.
3. Use of disallowed libraries.

All these rules can be found in the readme. By the looks of it, you have a print statement on the last line, which would automatically cause a compile error in the autograder.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually that print statement I added so that testers can test my code.

Comment: So, to clarify, you are getting the right answer for some test cases on your own compiler, but on Foobar even those test cases are being marked wrong?

Comment: Yes that is what happened.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry I do not know what the problem could be then

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect version of Python.

In `constraints.txt` file there is info:

> Your code will run inside a Python 2.7.13 sandbox. All tests will be
> run by calling the solution() function.

And your code uses function `list.copy()` which is allowed in Python 3.